# jump started toyota estima now no response from accelerator

Tags: toyota

my car was jumpstarted this morning and now the engine switches on but when i press the accelerator there is zero response. the gears can change to drive and reverse but the accelerator offers no response at all. it doesnt even cause the slightest rise in the revs. I did have some trouble a few weeks ago where all the lights on the dashboard began flashing and the rev counter began going up and down but that cleared after a few minutes... any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If your vehicle has a drive by wire throttle system, I'm betting you fried something there when doing the jump start. If so, it would most likely be the throttle pedal, because if the motor at the throttle body was bad, it would most likely throw a code. Also, you should get your battery and/or alternator looked at. Your description of the lights on the dashboard going wonky is an indication of a weak battery, which could be the battery itself or the alternator not putting out enough juice to keep it charged.

Comment: Did you check for blown fuses?